# Mosaic to New Raster output discolored

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, geotiff-tiff, merge, mosaic

I am attempting to mosaic 3 .tif files together using the Mosaic To New Raster tool in ArcGIS Pro. However every time I run the the tool the output comes out discolored (see attachment).

I have attempted changing Mosaic Operator and Mosaic Colormap Mode with no success. The .tif files I am trying to mosaic come from the same data source and all are 8 bit unsigned with 1 band.

Any idea where I am going wrong?[image][image] [image]

Comment: If they're 8 bit unsigned with a single band and are coloured when you add them to an ArcGIS map then they have a colour map. It's likely the colour maps are different. When the mosaic is created, the first colour map gets used which doesn't match the other rasters.

Comment: Try creating 3 band RGB layers using the [Colormap To RGB function](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.0/help/analysis/raster-functions/colormap-to-rgb-function.htm) and mosaicng those.